# Prompting user input() and using regular expression

Tags: python

I want to use regular expression to print all the text fragments in a list found in another text. Both texts are prompted by the user and the names (`egg` and `egg_carton` are just names, it's not about eggs). The following code prints an empty list. I think the problem is the `re.compile` part of the code, but I don't know how to fix this problem. I would like the code modified in it's form, not a completely other method of solving this problem. Appreciate it.

```
import re
egg= input()
egg_carton = input()
text_fragment = re.compile(r'(egg)')
find_all = text_fragment.findall(egg_carton)
print(find_all)
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input (and the value of `egg` with that sample input)?

Comment: So if the user writes egg = up and egg_carton = upupupup the program should output [up, up, up, up]

Comment: I get an empty list using this code

Comment: It's not clear whether you meant for `re.compile(r'(egg)')` to look for the actual string `'egg'`, or you want to look what that variable contains.

Comment: Agree with @kabanus. If you want to look for the value of `egg` in `egg_carton`, then you need to use: `text_fragment = re.compile(r'({0})'.format(egg))`. The `.format(egg)` converts `{0}` to contain the value of `egg`.

Comment: If I do that, I get `find_all = ["up", "up", "up", "up"]`, as you are looking for.

Comment: It's not the string egg but instead the input() supplied by the user

Comment: Yes so if `egg = "up"`, then `re.compile(r'({0})').format(egg))` is equivalent to `re.compile(r'(up)')`

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification. Interesting. What is the .format(egg) exactly?

Comment: why do you put 0 in {0}?

Comment: Look up string formatting with `.format` in the Python specifications for your version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look for the value of `egg` (i.e. `egg = "up"`) in `egg_carton` (i.e. `egg_carton = "upupupup"`), then you need to use:

```
text_fragment = re.compile(r'({0})'.format(egg))
```

The [`.format(egg)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) converts `{0}` to contain the value of `egg`. Therefore, if `egg = "up"`, it would be equivalent to:

```
text_fragment = re.compile(r'(up)')
```

Putting this all together:

```
import re
egg= raw_input()
egg_carton = raw_input()
text_fragment = re.compile(r'({0})'.format(egg)) # same as: re.compile(r'(up)')
find_all = text_fragment.findall(egg_carton)
print(find_all)
```

Gives me this output:

```
['up', 'up', 'up', 'up']
```

You can find more information on the `"string".format()` function in the Python3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format